# laravel 5.6 default login with ajax gives 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I am using laravel 5.6 and I am trying to login with ajax. I have set all the things =>csrf ajax setup and also passing token, but I am still getting this when all credentials are right:
[image: screenshot]

THis is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sign-in-form').submit(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        formData = $('#sign-in-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('login')}}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function () {
                //  element.value='Processing...';
            },
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: So, in the console, you can see that your password is less than 6 characters.

Comment: i am gettings this bad request when i am entering correct records

Comment: the error says your email doesn't exist in your database.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your codes. The message is the result of validations. To solve your issue you may need to enter at least 6 characters or more for your password and that should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are right but it is bad request and we can not process it for showing error message to the users

Comment: @Saimikram84 just update the validation message or validation rules in the code.